# Unexpected asynchronous like behavior

Tags: php, html

I came across an unexpected behavior while creating drop downs.

**DropDown.php**

```
function getValue($content, $options){
    if($options["valueByName"])
        return $content;
    else
        return $content["value"];
}

function getName($content, $options){
    if($options["valueByName"])
        return $content;
    else
        return $content["name"];
}

function isSelected($content, $options){
    if(isset($options["selected"])){
        if(getValue($content, $options) == $options["selected"])
            return " selected ";
        else
            return "";
        }
    else
        if(getValue($content, $options)=="")
            return " selected ";
        else
            return "";
}

function renderOption($content, $options){
    echo (
        "<option value=\"".getValue($content, $options)."\""
                          .isSelected($content, $options).">"
            .getName($content, $options).
        "</option>");
}
$asdf123 = 0; #<-------------------------------------IMPORTANT
function DropDownMenu($contents, $options)
{
    $id = $options["id"];
    $name = $options["name"];
    $style = $options["style"];
    $flag = $options["flag"];
    $firstIsDefault = $options["firstIsDefault"];
    
    global $asdf123; #<-------------------------------------IMPORTANT
    echo($asdf123++);
    echo ("<select id=\"{$id}\" 
                   name=\"{$name}\"
                   class=\"btn 
                           btn-outline-secondary 
                           waves-effect 
                           waves-light 
                           keyword_selector\" 
                   style=\"width:140px; 
                           height: 22px; 
                           float:left;height:35px; 
                           padding: 4px 14px; 
                           {$style}\"
                   {$flag}>");
    if($firstIsDefault){
        echo (
            "<option value ".isSelected($contents[0], $options).">"  
                .getName($contents[0], $options).
            "</option>");
        for($i = 1; $i < count($contents); $i++)
            renderOption($contents[$i], $options);
        
    }else{
        foreach ($contents as $i => $content)
            renderOption($content, $options);
    }
    
    echo ("</select>");
}
```

**Using Drop Down(in another php file)**

```
require_once("DropDown.php");
DropDownMenu($customers, [
    "id"=>"customer-dropdown",
    "name"=>"customer_id",
    "firstIsDefault"=> true
]);

DropDownMenu($classes, [
    "id"=>"class-dropdown",
    "name"=>"class",
    "firstIsDefault"=> true,
    "style"=>"margin-left:5px;"
]);

# Total 7 times called
```

**Results In**

| DropDown | DropDown | 01 DropDown | 0 DropDown | 2345 DropDown | DropDown | DropDown |

**Behavior**

When I checked the elements in browser, all of the `option` element were `<option value="" selected="">text was different</option>`. Where expected behavior is only the first `option` being `selected`.
I added variable `asdf123` in `DropDown.php` to look what was happening. And as noted above `Results in`, is printed in the sequence of  `0 1 0 2 3 4 5`.
Why would this happen? Are PHP functions asynchronous? What is happening? What could be the cause?

> EDIT: I have fixed all of the options were `selected` part. It was because I was using the `key` in the `$contents` were wrong. Instead of `"value"` I used `"id"`. But I still don't know why the execution sequence was messed up.

Comment: No PHP functions are not asynchronous. It doesn't look like async behaviour to me, more like some repetition of calls somewhere.

Comment: As for the "all the options were selected " bit, as far as I can see from the code above, that isn't possible. But, are you sure the above is definitely the right version of the code? Because when I tried to run it, it was throwing lots of errors until I added more fields to the options array. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d52ad2ad5caad8dd7b5b1fefef81f968710a0190

Comment: @ADyson I am currently using the code as it is except the `$asdf123` variable is deleted.  I coded it so that if not in `$options` it would pass. You could''ve gotten warnings for variable being unassigned. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I do get notices for those if I omit them. Maybe you've suppressed notices in your install so you don't see them? To me, that scenario is a bug though. But anyway, the main point is that it doesn't reproduce the "all the options were selected " problem. So we can't help you with that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$customers=[[value=>a,name=>aa], [value=>b,name=>bb], [value=>c,name=>cc]];  // needed to tests
$classes=[[value=>A,name=>AA], [value=>B,name=>BB], [value=>C,name=>CC]];    // needed to tests

$asdf123 = 0;
function getValue($content, $options){      return  ($options[valueByName]) ? $content : $content[value];}
function getName($content, $options){       return  ($options[valueByName]) ? $content : $content[name];}
function isSelected($content, $options){    return  (getValue($content, $options) == $options[selected]) ? ' selected' : '';}
function renderOption($content, $options){  echo '<option value="'.getValue($content, $options)."\"".isSelected($content, $options).">".getName($content, $options)."</option>\r\n";    }
function DropDownMenu($contents, $options){
    echo    $GLOBALS[asdf123]++."\r\n";
    foreach([id, name, style, flag, firstIsDefault] as $val){   $$val = $options[$val];}
    echo "<select id=\"$id\" name=\"$name\" \r\n class=\"btn btn-outline-secondary waves-effect waves-light keyword_selector\"\r\n style=\"width: 140px; height: 22px; float: left; height: 35px; padding: 4px 14px; \r\n $style\" \r\n $flag>\r\n";
    if($firstIsDefault){
        echo '<option value=""'.isSelected($contents[0], $options).'>'.getName($contents[0], $options)."</option>\r\n";     // lost ' ="value" ' , ' " ' , html syntax!!!!
        $j = count($contents);                              // don't count every time
        for($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++){    renderOption($contents[$i], $options);} }           // $i < $j is incomplete
    else{   foreach ($contents as $key => $content) renderOption($content, $options);}
    echo "</select>\r\n";}
DropDownMenu($customers, [id=>'customer-dropdown', name=>customer_id, firstIsDefault=> 1]);
DropDownMenu($classes, [id=>'class-dropdown', name=>'class', firstIsDefault=> true, style=>'margin-left:5px;']);
```

Just clean up, fix html and css syntax, fill empty values and will work fine.
`Selected` is only last option - as you set it.
... that's not pretty code, you know?

For html, css use [Validator](https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/?ucn_lang=en), please